# JS reduce return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reduce

There is array of objects

```
this.props.comments = [{
id: "b149b076-93b1-4ac7-b913-65a7b1ee9a5b", 
addedBy: "user1", 
addedById: "3dc8e8a0-dc40-42da-ae53-f10b01a0b197", 
addedDate: "2018-10-08T10:47:46.829258", 
content: "test1"
}, {
id: "ee997e10-919c-42cc-8efb-7ea49cf5c197", 
addedBy: "user22", 
addedById: "1781e165-82f4-4a49-884c-ba66031ad0da", 
addedDate: "2018-10-08T10:41:59.264111", 
content: "test2"}]
```

I am trying to filter and output comments using `reduce`

```
const comments = this.props.comments.reduce((result, cm, index) => {
            if(cm.addedById === "3dc8e8a0-dc40-42da-ae53-f10b01a0b197") {
                result += <li key={index} className="task-comments__comment">
                    <p className="task-comments__comment-header">
                        <span className="task-comments__comment-author">{ cm.addedBy }</span>
                        <span
                            className="task-comments__comment-date">
                            {moment(cm.addedDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM')}
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="task-comments__comment-text">
                        { cm.content }
                    </p>
                </li>;
            }
            return result;
        }, {});
```

but as result I get
[image]

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use `filter`? seems like you want to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Also, how can you do `result += <li key={index} ...`? you are adding something which is not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating objects.

Instead, `result` should be an array.

```
const comments = this.props.comments.reduce((result, cm, index) => {
        if(cm.addedById === "3dc8e8a0-dc40-42da-ae53-f10b01a0b197") {
            result.push(<li key={index} className="task-comments__comment">
                <p className="task-comments__comment-header">
                    <span className="task-comments__comment-author">{ cm.addedBy }</span>
                    <span
                        className="task-comments__comment-date">
                        {moment(cm.addedDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM')}
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p className="task-comments__comment-text">
                    { cm.content }
                </p>
            </li>);
        }
        return result;
    }, []);
```

Comment: @Heidel If result should be an array then don't use `reduce`, use `map`

Comment: @slebetman why? I need not only `map`, I also need to filter the array

Comment: @Heidel P.s. using `filter` instead of `reduce` is more than reasonable here.
My goal was just to locate an issue in the current code.

Comment: @Heidel P.s.s. check out functions for arrays and objects here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10  

Some of them are available in pure javascript http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array

Comment: I tried to use `filter` https://jsfiddle.net/hvztgusp/ but I get an error `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return`

Comment: @Heidel https://jsfiddle.net/hvztgusp/1/ at first you `filter` comments and then you `map` them into react components.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not describe what exactly is it that you want, I've made some guesses:

First lets use `map` to create a new modified Array and last lets use `filter` to filter out empty array items, since the map will create those (because of the `if` statement)

Last, I would advise to *separate* the HTML from the logic:

```js
const comments = this.props.comments.map((item, index) => {
    if(item.addedById === "3dc8e8a0-dc40-42da-ae53-f10b01a0b197")
        return createListItem(item, index);
}).filter(Boolean);

function createListItem(item, index){
  return <li key={index} className="task-comments__comment">
      <p className="task-comments__comment-header">
          <span className="task-comments__comment-author">{ item.addedBy }</span>
          <span className="task-comments__comment-date">
              {moment(item.addedDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM')}
          </span>
      </p>
      <p className="task-comments__comment-text">{ item.content }</p>
  </li>
}
```